# Detect window focus changes with XCB

Tags: c, x11, xlib, xcb

I'm writing a program with XCB that needs to detect whenever a window gains or loses focus. So far I have this but it just hangs on the `xcb_wait_for_event` call, never entering the loop. What am I missing here to grab root events? Or am I just going about this totally wrong and there's a better way than listening to the root?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    xcb_connection_t* conn = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
    if (xcb_connection_has_error(conn)) {
        printf("Cannot open daemon connection.");
        return 0;
    }

    xcb_screen_t* screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(conn)).data;

    uint32_t values[] = { XCB_EVENT_MASK_FOCUS_CHANGE };
    xcb_change_window_attributes(
        conn,
        screen->root,
        XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK,
        values);

    xcb_generic_event_t *ev;
    while ((ev = xcb_wait_for_event(conn))) {
        printf("IN LOOP\n");
        switch (ev->response_type & 0x7F) {
        case XCB_FOCUS_IN:
        case XCB_FOCUS_OUT:
            printf("IN CASE\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("IN DEFAULT\n");
            break;
        }
        free(ev);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The focus events are only sent when the window that you selected these events on receives or loses the focus, see https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/x11proto/proto.html:

> FocusIn
>   FocusOut
>
> [...]
>
> These events are generated when the input focus changes and are reported to clients selecting FocusChange on the window.

To use this, you would have to select this event mask on all windows and also watch for the creation of new windows.

---

I would suggest a different approach: Watch for PropertyChangeNotify events on the root window to see when the `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` property changes. This property should be kept up to date by the WM, according to EWMH.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

static xcb_atom_t intern_atom(xcb_connection_t *conn, const char *atom)
{
    xcb_atom_t result = XCB_NONE;
    xcb_intern_atom_reply_t *r = xcb_intern_atom_reply(conn,
            xcb_intern_atom(conn, 0, strlen(atom), atom), NULL);
    if (r)
        result = r->atom;
    free(r);
    return result;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    xcb_connection_t* conn = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
    if (xcb_connection_has_error(conn)) {
        printf("Cannot open daemon connection.");
        return 0;
    }

    xcb_atom_t active_window = intern_atom(conn, "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW");
    xcb_screen_t* screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(conn)).data;

    uint32_t values[] = { XCB_EVENT_MASK_PROPERTY_CHANGE };
    xcb_change_window_attributes(
        conn,
        screen->root,
        XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK,
        values);

    xcb_flush(conn);

    xcb_generic_event_t *ev;
    while ((ev = xcb_wait_for_event(conn))) {
        printf("IN LOOP\n");
        switch (ev->response_type & 0x7F) {
        case XCB_PROPERTY_NOTIFY: {
            xcb_property_notify_event_t *e = (void *) ev;
            if (e->atom == active_window)
                puts("active window changed");
            break;
        }
        default:
            printf("IN DEFAULT\n");
            break;
        }
        free(ev);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot when I can. In the meantime, would you mind explaining a bit what's going on in your `intern_atom` function? As an X11/xcb rookie it's hard to parse what's going on there.

Comment: Atoms are basically arbitrary strings, like here `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW`. However, strings do not have a fixed length. So you ask the X11 server for the `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` atom and it gives you back a number. The number has a fixed length and now you can always use this number to refer to this string. Other X11 clients that ask for this atom get back the same number. Atoms are e.g. used for window properties: The kind of property is an atom (e.g. `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` or `_WM_CLASS`), the type of the property is an atom (e.g. `WINDOW` or `UTF8_STRING)` etc.