# XCB: detect change of a window's name / title

Tags: c, linux, events, window, xcb

XCB allows us to...

- read a window's name (title) via the `WM_NAME` and `_NET_WM_NAME` properties
- monitor for changes in window properties via `XCB_EVENT_MASK_PROPERTY_CHANGE`

I'm successfully doing both of these. Specifically, here is how I monitor for changes in the `_NET_WM_NAME` property of all windows (by subscribing to events on the root window):

```
/* ... */

const uint32_t list[] = { XCB_EVENT_MASK_PROPERTY_CHANGE };
xcb_change_window_attributes(conn, root_window, XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK, &list);
xcb_flush(conn);

xcb_generic_event_t *evt;
while ((evt = xcb_wait_for_event(conn)))
{
    if (evt->response_type == XCB_PROPERTY_NOTIFY)
    {
        xcb_property_notify_event_t *e = (void *) evt;
        /* ... print the window name ... */
    }
    free(evt);
}

/* ... */
```

This seems to work fine for the most part, but I've noticed that I don't receive an event when I change tabs within my browser, even though that does change the browser window's title.

Am I doing it wrong or is that not possible with XCB?

---

Credit for the above code mostly goes to [this answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57910188/3316645).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specifically, here is how I monitor for changes in the _NET_WM_NAME property of all windows (by subscribing to events on the root window):

The code you show does not monitor property changes of all windows. It only monitors for property changes on the root window.

If you want to listen on property changes on all windows... well, it's complicated. You can select for `SubstructureNotify`. This should give you `CreateNotify` events whenever a new sub-window is created. For that window, you would again select `SubstructureNotify` etc to get all windows, recursively.

For each of the windows you found this will, you also want to send a `QueryTree` request to get its children. You also have to select the events for the child windows which already existed before your program started.

Of course, you should also select for `PropertyNotifyMask` while you are requesting `SubstructureNotify`. That way, you should get informed whenever any window changes any property (*).

(*): Well, of course it is possible for something to create a window and immediately change a property. Most likely, this property will be set before you get a chance to ask for `PropertyNotify`. Thus, if you really want to see all properties, you also need a `ListProperties` request on the windows after you asked for property changes...

Comment: Ah, your first sentence cleared up where I was going wrong. First, I was wondering why I would get an event every time I changed the active window -  even though you said I'm not monitoring for changes of all windows. But now I see: because the root window's `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` property changes when focusing another window - but it wouldn't change when switching tabs within the _same_ window. It all makes sense now.